# How to use grep and sed in order to replace the substring after searching some specific string?

Tags: linux, string, replace, sed, grep

I want to know how to use two 'grep' and 'sed' utilities or something else in order to replace the substring. I will explain what I want to do below.

We have the file 'test.txt' with the following string:

> A1='AA1', A2='AA2', A3='AA3', A4='AA4', A5{ATTR}='AA5', A6='keyword_A'

After searching 'keyword_A' using grep, I want to replace the value of A5 with other string, for example, "NEW".

> A1='AA1', A2='AA2', A3='AA3', A4='AA4', A5{ATTR}='NEW', A6='keyword_A'

I tried to use two commands like

```
grep keyword_A test.txt | sed -e 's/blabla/blabla/'
```

After trying all I know, I gave up at all.

Please let me know the right solution.

Comment: see also [sed doc examples for such problems](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range#t=201701240411428268083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you never need grep **and** sed. Sed has a full regular-expression search engine, so it is a superset of grep. This command will read `test.txt`, change the lines that you've indicated, and print the entire result on standard output:

```
sed "/keyword_A/s/A5{ATTR}='[A-Z0-9]*'/A5{ATTR}='NEW'/g" < test.txt
```

If you want to store the results back into the file `test.txt`, use the `-i` (in-place editing) switch to `sed`:

```
sed "/keyword_A/s/A5{ATTR}='[A-Z0-9]*'/A5{ATTR}='NEW'/g" -i.bak test.txt
```

If you want to select *only* the indicated lines, modify those, and print only those lines to standard out, use a combination of the `p` (print) command and the `-n` (no output) switch.

```
sed "/keyword_A/s/A5{ATTR}='[A-Z0-9]*'/A5{ATTR}='NEW'/gp" -n test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Using grep+sed is always the wrong approach. Here's one way to do it with GNU awk:

```
$ awk '/keyword_A/{ $0=gensub(/(A5({[^}]+})?=\047)[^\047]+/,"\\1NEW",1) } 1' file
A1='AA1', A2='AA2', A3='AA3', A4='AA4', A5{ATTR}='NEW', A6='keyword_A'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a couple variables you could define the keyword and replacement ( if they change at all ):

```
q="keyword_A"
r="NEW"
```

Then with `sed`:

```
sed -r "s/^(.+\{.+\}=')(.+)('.+"${q}".+)$/\1"${r}"\3/" file
```

**Result:**

```
A1='AA1', A2='AA2', A3='AA3', A4='AA4', A5{ATTR}='NEW', A6='keyword_A'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A5="NEW"
A6="keyword_A"

# with sed
sed "s/='[^']*\(',[[:blank:]]*A6='${A6}'\)/='${A5}\1/" YourFile

# with awk
awk -F "'" -v A5="${A5}" -v A6="${A6}" '
   BEGIN { OFS="\047" }
   $12 == A6 { $10 = A5; $0 = $0 }
   7
   ' YourFile
```

- Change by the end of the string, for sed and using `'` as field separator in awk instead of traditional space.
- assuming there is no `'` in value (or need to treat the escaping method) for awk version

Answer (score 0):

We can just directly replace the fifth column when the sting keyword_A is found as shown below:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=",";}/keyword_A/{$5="A5{ATTR}='"'"NEW"'"'"}1' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of slight alternatives:

```
sed -r "/keyword_A/s/(A5[^']*')[^']*/\1NEW/"

awk -F"'" '/keyword_A/{$10 = "NEW"}1' OFS="'"
```

Of course the negative with awk is afterwards you would have to rename the new file.